# Best way to align multiple RESTful API's through an API gateway

Tags: design, rest, api, api-design, azure

We currently have a monolith public api which serves most of our api endpoints. This has introduced a bottleneck as the owning team needs to make changes to publicise anything new and other teams don't have control over their own endpoints.

To remove this we're looking to introduce an azure app gateway which will break this monolith out into team owned product apis.

Due to the way the api is structured there's not clear routing in the already used endpoints to facilitate an easy split up.

To keep this fully RESTful we would need many complex routing rules which would only grow over time as new API's and endpoints are added.

Another option is to effectively preface each of these product apis into "areas" and allow easy routing through that.

This makes it less restful but much easier to maintain and expand on going forward.

Any thoughts on what could be a way forward would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you ignored the "hypermedia" part of REST and your problems are a direct consequence of that. Is the application state based on navigation with hypermedia? I.e. following links and/or submitting forms?

Comment: REST does not care about the naming of end-points, so adding an area indicator into the path does not make your system less (or more) RESTful.